# Lesscss one level up mixing

Tags: less, mixins

pretty sure this isn't at all possible but ...

Say I have this mixin:

```
.horizontalList() {
    background:blue;
        & li {
            display:inline-block;
        }
}
```

The css it generates is:

```
.something{
    background:blue;
}

.something li{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Is it possible to generate the following CSS using a similar mixin?

```
.something{
    background:blue;
}

.something li{
    display:inline-block;
}

.ie6 .something li,
.ie7 .something li
{
    display:inline;
}
```

... So the ie6 and ie7 stuff is before the selector and I can make use of the [Paul Irish conditional comments idea](http://paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/)

I know that I could add a css hack to do the old IE stuff but I prefer not to have these in my stylesheet.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do it in the mixin:

**LESS**

```
.horizontalList() {
    background:blue;
        & li {
            display:inline-block;
        }
        .ie6 & li,
        .ie7 & li {
            display: inline;
        }
}
```

**Call It**

```
.something {
  .horizontalList;
}
```

**CSS Output**

```
.something {
  background: blue;
}
.something li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.ie6 .something li,
.ie7 .something li {
  display: inline;
}
```